# How to get intel MKL's cblas_dgemm and pardiso solvers in python?

Tags: python, pardiso

I try to use Intel mkl from python. The only document I have found suggested the following:

```
from ctypes import *

# Load the share library
mkl = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libmkl_rt.so")
# For Intel MKL prior to version 10.3 us the created .so as below
# mkl = dll.LoadLibrary("./libmkl4py.so")
cblas_dgemm = mkl.cblas_dgemm
```

I am on anaconda3. The code above does not work on anaconda3,

```
OSError: ./libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but I can use

```
import mkl
```

directly. Yet I do not find any documents on what to do next after `import mkl`. For example, how can I get the `cblas_dgemm` function as in the example above. Calling `mkl.cblas_dgemm` directly does not work on my anaconda (after import mkl). Any idea? In the end, I hope to invoke Intel MKL's pardiso solver but really have no idea although `import mkl` works on my anaconda.